# ASTreeView help! (using JavaScript with .dll's)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I love the demos of [ASTreeView](http://www.astreeview.com/). I'd like to use this in my project, which is *completely local* and currently only uses HTML, JavaScript, and CSS - i.e. no ASP.net or anything dealing with servers...

Is it possible for me to use this? There is a .dll and a .js included in the package, but I have no clue where to start since this isn't a ASP.net project for me. I can't find any documentation on this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASTreeView is a ASP.NET server side control. It is used on .aspx pages that are typically run on Microsoft IIS servers or any other server supporting ASP.NET. Take a look at [ASTreeView - Free ASP.NET TreeView Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ASTreeView.aspx) on CodeProject.com for a nice tutorial on this free control.